# Dificuldade ao baixar e instalar Bibliotecas de Python

Tags: python

Eu pesquisei bastante, mas não encontrei um jeito de baixar e instalar bibliotecas para python no computador. Não estou com um erro ao baixar, ou erro ao instalar. Somente não sei como fazer isso. Precisa de ajuda nisto.

Comment: Quando diz "bibliotecas de Python" você se refere às bibliotecas padrões do Python ? Se é isso, elas já vem na instalação do Python dentro da pasta `Python/Python<version>/Lib`.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Desculpa. Não estou falando dessas. Mas mesmo que eu tivesse falando dessas bibliotecas, não existe essa pasta /Lib, nos arquivos do Python

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Descobri como instalar. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

caso queira instalar qualquer outra biblioteca, eu aconselho usar o PIP

sudo apt-get install python3-pip (para instalar caso seja sistema linux)

pip install 'pacote'

Ex.: pip install tensorflow